# Trying to build a basic calculator using multiple classes

Tags: java

I am trying to use multiple classes not to bulk the whole entirety of the calculator in the main class. I was planning to use switch but I have been stuck on trying to combine User Input when it comes to your choice of operation.

1. ApplesUserInput.java

```
package applesuserinput;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ApplesUserInput {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        calculator c1 = new calculator();
        
        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to my Calculator.");
        System.out.print("You may add (A), subtract (S), multiply (M) or divide (D) two different numbers. Please select one of the letters for your desired operation: ");
        calculator.geta();
  
    }
    
}
```

2. calculator.java

```
package applesuserinput;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {
    public static void geta(){
        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a;
    a = scan.nextLine();
    
}
    
}
```

So far it compiles and runs well but I cannot get the switch statement to recognize the a String from my geta(). So I'm pretty much stuck here right now.

Comment: Did you want to `return` the string from `geta()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **geta()** method isn't returning anything, nor have you assigned the result to anything.

It should be:

```
  public static String geta(){
    
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = scan.nextLine();
return a;


}
```

And in ApplesUserInput.java, it should be:

```
String a = calculator.geta();
```

Comment: It works now! I only had however to add 'static' to public String geta() otherwise it wouldn't let me reference String a = calculator.geta(); in ApplesUserInput.java. Thanks, though!